# Querying a many-to-many relationship with added difficulty

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my problem:
I have two tables connected trough a junction table.
I'm using MySQL and PHP (Yii2) on an Apache server, but its just the SQL i need help with.

```
| Objects     |    ObjectHasTag    |   Tag    |
|---------------------------------------------|
| - id        |    -object_id      |   -id    |
| - name      |    -tag_id         |   -tag   |
```

I need to create a query that returns objects that is tagged with several tags, and my question is if this is doable with reasonable efficiency as a publicly accessible feature as a query.

Example: find all objects with tags 'tagone', 'tagtwo' and 'tagthree'.

I have one solution that works, and that is to have a 'tags'-column in the Objects-table, with all the tag-names divided by commas. This does not seem like a 'best practice'-kinda solution.

I really appreciate any help you guys can provide!

Comment: I did not even have a clue where to start with the SQL Query. dasblinkenlight gave a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL for this is relatively straightforward:

```
SELECT *
FROM Objects o
WHERE 3 = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.id)
    FROM ObjectHasTag ot
    JOIN Tag t ON t.id=ot.tag_id
    WHERE o.id = ot.object_id
      AND t.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
)
```

The `COUNT(DISTINCT t.id)` joins `ObjectHasTag` to `Tag`, filters `Tag` on the list that you would like to search, and counts the number of distinct tags. In order for the object to be selected, all three items from the `IN` list must be present. If you know that `ObjectHasTag` cannot contain duplicate tagging, for example, because you have a unique index or a constraint on the table, you can replace `COUNT(DISTINCT t.id)` with `COUNT(*)`.

The `o.id = ot.object_id` condition "connects" the nested query to the object selected from `Objects` table.